# loading .jpn images in reactJs

Tags: css, reactjs

I have just configured my project with  style-loader and css-loader -

```
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loaders: ['babel'],
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'scripts')
      },{
            test: /\.css$/,
            loaders: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
        }
    ]
  }
```

Which works perfectly but then i encountered a problem with my .jpn image.

> ERROR in ./scripts/radio.jpg Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\barak\WebstormProjects\FinalProjectRadioStream\scripts\radioo.jpg
>   Unexpected character '�' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to
>   handle this file type.

Any recommendations about images loaders? some simple way for using images in css files with react and webpack?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using webpack.
You need to config for image loader files like this (use 'file-loader'):

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {}  
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/